# Данные из базы данных в txt файл

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Всем привет! Есть веб приложение с базой студентов (id, Имя, возраст, сумма баллов)
Хочу сделать выборку из базы 5 студентов с самыми высокими баллами и сохранить в txt файл.
Так выглядит выборка 5 студентов для представления

```
StudentContext db = new StudentContext();
    public ActionResult ShowTopFive ()
            {
                var allStudents = db.Students.OrderByDescending(s => s.SumNote).Take(5);
                return PartialView(allStudents);
            }
```

Класс студента такой

```
public class Student
    {
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public int FirstNote { get; set; }
        public int SecondNote { get; set; }
        public int ThirdNote { get; set; }
        public int SumNote { get; set; }

    }
```

Как можно сохранить данные по 5 лучшим студентам в формате Name, SumNote?

Comment: Давно заметил закономерность: большинство задающих вопрос с тегом asp.net (mvc) не указывают язык программирования (c#, vb.net, f#, etc). С чем это связано? Если язык вам действительно не важен, прямо пишите это. А так, многие следят именно за вопросами по _языку_, поэтому указав его, вы получите больше шансов на ответ.

Comment: Я не понял: судя по тегу asp.net mvc, вы хотите на _клиенте_ получить данные и сохранить их в файл? Или на _сервере_ нужно из БД в файл переписать прямо в контроллере?

Comment: Чтобы по нажатию клавиши из БД отбирались данные и предлагали сохранить в файле

Comment: может целесообразнее будет сначала вывести данные на клиенте, и прикрутить кнопку "сохранить в файл"??